# If $M \otimes_K L$ is a free $A \otimes_K L$ module, is $M$ a free $A$ module? $L$ is a field extension of $K$.

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

$M$ is finitely generated. $L$ is a field extension of $K$.

*Question*: If $M \otimes_K L$ is a free $A \otimes_K L$ module, is $M$ a free $A$ module?

I am asking this because I am trying to show that smoothness of a $K$-variety (in the sense that the cotangent bundle is locally free of correct dimension) can be checked after basechange to a field extension $L$ of $K$.

The converse is easy (that $M$ is a free $A$ module, then $M \otimes_k L$ is a free $A \otimes_K L$ module is immediate by writing down an isomorphism of $0 \to A^{\oplus n } \to M \to 0$, then tensoring with $\_ \otimes_k L$ and using flatness of vector spaces, and that $\otimes$ commutes with direct sums). (Really one just needs flatness for this direction.)

Maybe the statement is false? It's possible that one only gets $M$ is locally free. (That would also work for my purposes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is that

$$M\otimes_KL=M\otimes_A(A\otimes_KL)$$

is finite free over $A\otimes_KL$. If you want to deduce that $M$ is finite projective over $A$, all you need is to assume that $M\otimes_KL$ is finite projective over $A\otimes_KL$. Note that the ring map $A\to A\otimes_KL$ is the base change of $K\to L$ along $K\to A$, and so is faithfully flat. Then if $M\otimes_KL$ is finite projective over $A\otimes_KL$, it follows that $M$ is finite projective over $A$ (see http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/058S).

Comment: Thanks! So is it a fact that basechange of a faithfully flat is faithfully flat? (To conclude that $A \to A \otimes_K L$ is faithfully flat from knowing $K \to L$ is?)

Comment: Dear @AreaMan, Yes, this is true.

Comment: Do we get anything precise about the rank of the $M$? I guess need that the rank is the same in order to conclude smoothness. Though I guess it doesn't happen, it is conceivable that weird things could happen if the base change was along something inseparable.

Comment: I guess the rank can be seen to be equal just by checking the fibers at the $L$ points.